# Why keyStore.aliases() is empty for pkcs12

Tags: java, security, encryption, bouncycastle

I'm trying to load PrivateKey from .p12 file by using this code:

```
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    java.security.KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("my_domain_com.p12")), password);
    keyStore.aliases().hasMoreElements(); //this is false
    java.security.PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("SomeAlias", password);
```

I'm trying to find the reason why there is no aliases. But I'm not able to find.
What can be reason for the empty alias? 
I want to get private key and ecrypt some text using this key. Is there other apporach?

I also have .cer file but I'm not sure I should use together.

Answer (score 6):

Is it possible the keystore has nothing in it at all?  Use the Java `keytool` command to verify.

```
>keytool -list -v -keystore test.p12 -storetype PKCS12
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: test_alias
Creation date: Sep 3, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
...
...
```

If there are entries in the keystore, you should see an "Alias name" for each one.  If there are no entries in the keystore, you will see "Your keystore contains 0 entries", and you will need to import them into the keystore.

Also, when encrypting, you should encrypt with someone else's public key, and they will decrypt with their private key.  And they encrypt with your public key, which you decrypt with your private key.

Comment: Thanks for your response, It is giving: _Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 0 entries_ 
And then imported it to keystore: `keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore my_domain_com.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore truststore.jks -deststoretype JKS` And it says: _Import command completed:  0 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled
[Storing truststore.jks]_

Comment: That confirms my suspicion.  Your keystore is empty.  You need to generate or import keys into your keystore before you can use it.

Comment: it was used for SSL certificates and VeriSign stuffs. Is it possible to use these file for encryption and decryption?

Comment: You can't use that keystore for anything.  It is empty. There are no keys in it.  I don't know how it was used SSL either.  You need to import a key into the keystore before it can be used.