# How to generate or import keys into your keystore?

Tags: ssl-certificate, keystore, jks, pkcs#12

I need to import a .p12 file into a .jks certificate and in this question it says that I need to import entries into the keystore, but actually I'm not understanding what entries do I have to import and in which keystore I need to do that.

[Why keyStore.aliases() is empty for pkcs12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600126/why-keystore-aliases-is-empty-for-pkcs12)

I'm starting in this of the certificates and this is only to do a test with jmeter but it only accepts .jks into the SSL server.properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I find to transform the .p12 file into a .jks was better a tool called "KeyStore Explorer" that's better than keep fighting with the keytool command in Windows. I recommend it!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.webfarmr.eu/2010/04/import-pkcs12-private-keys-into-jks-keystores-using-java-keytool/). I think it solves your conversion from .p12 to .jks problem.

Comment: The problem is that when I do this it gives me this response: "Import command completed: 0 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled [Storing something.jks]". Thas why I need to generate or import keys into my keystore. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @cagoscra could you post the exactly commands  you're trying to run?